# After interrupting Queue.get(timeout=60), the following Queue.get() does not return after another thread has succesfully Queue.put('something'). Why?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, queue, python-multithreading

I've already worked around this but I'm wondering what I was doing wrong.
I created a Queue.Queue() and erroneously called get(timeout=60). The queue was empty so the call blocked. I interrupted it with CTRL-C. I instantiated a secondary threading.Thread which, after a sleep, would populate the queue. While the secondary thread was sleeping I called get() which again blocked. When the secondary thread awoke it populated the queue but the main get() did not return. Why?

The file secondary.py:

```
import time, threading
class putter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, q):
        super(putter, self).__init__()
        self.q = q
        self._keep_going = True
    def stop(self):
        self._keep_going = False
    def run(self):
        print('T2 sleeping to allow calling get')
        time.sleep(5)
        print('T2 awoke, putting')
        self.q.put('Hello world!')
        while self._keep_going:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('{} T2 running'.format(time.time()))
            print('qsize {}'.format(self.q.qsize()))
```

The interactive interpreter session:

```
bruno@jeeg:/mnt/storage/src/foo$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Queue
>>> from secondary import putter
>>> queue = Queue.Queue()
>>> queue.get(timeout=60)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 177, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> p = putter(queue)
>>> p.start()
T2 sleeping to allow calling get

>>> queue.get()
T2 awoke, putting
1491384824.07 T2 running
qsize 1
1491384825.08 T2 running
qsize 1
1491384826.08 T2 running
qsize 1
1491384827.08 T2 running
[... forever]
```

Another session, testing for @Himal

```
>>> p.start()
T2 sleeping to allow calling get
>>> queue.get(timeout=4)
T2 awoke, putting
1491401131.61 T2 running
qsize 1
1491401132.61 T2 running
qsize 1
'Hello world!'
>>> 1491401133.61 T2 running
qsize 0
1491401134.61 T2 running
qsize 0
[... T2 keeps running but now get(timeout=4) has returned and the queue is empty]
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with this code. can you try to put a timeout in your `queue.get()` so we can know for sure if it's blocking ? use a value larger than 5.

Comment: @Himal You know  `queue.get()` is blocking because "Hello world!" is never printed.

Comment: But it doesn't hurt to try it right ?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `get()` returned, but the interactive interpreter session didn't. The reason for the latter most likely is that the other thread was still running, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Try to run this program:

```
import time, threading
class putter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, q):
        super(putter, self).__init__()
        self.q = q
        self._keep_going = True
    def stop(self):
        self._keep_going = False
    def run(self):
        print('T2 sleeping to allow calling get')
        time.sleep(5)
        print('T2 awoke, putting')
        self.q.put('Hello world!')
        while self._keep_going:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('{} T2 running'.format(time.time()))
            print('qsize {}'.format(self.q.qsize()))

from Queue import Queue

q = Queue()

p = putter(q)
p.start()

q.get()

print("Get returned!")
```

Which will correctly print the following output:

```
T2 sleeping to allow calling get
T2 awoke, putting
Get returned!
1491386038.93 T2 running
qsize 0
1491386039.93 T2 running
qsize 0
1491386040.94 T2 running
qsize 0
...
```

When I run the following code in my interactive interpreter, the output is as expected and the command even returns (see the `>>>` in the line after `Get returned!`). The latter might be different from your result because we're using different operating systems.

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from so_test import putter
>>> from Queue import Queue
>>> q = Queue()
>>> putter(q).start()
T2 sleeping to allow calling get
>>> q.get(); print("Get returned!")
T2 awoke, putting
'Hello world!'
Get returned!
>>> 1491387024.89 T2 running
qsize 0
1491387025.89 T2 running
qsize 0
1491387026.89 T2 running
qsize 0
1491387027.89 T2 running
qsize 0
1491387028.9 T2 running
...
```

Comment: For others trying to reproduce the interactive session: I couldn't terminate the program by using `CTRL-C` and would like to know if that's just my system.

Comment: If you don't pass the timeout to `Queue.get()` you can't interrupt it. Perhaps that was the issue.

Comment: Both in your code and in your interactive interpreter session you didn't CTRL-C on a blocking get(timeout=60). I suspect it's the CTRL-C which is messing up something in the queue.